# My ban command argument requirements don't seem to be working (Bukkit)

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

I am trying to create a GUI that contains various punishments and I'm having an issue with my messages going through to the player when they should be going through. For example, if I run /ban in game with no argument afterwards, I want it to say "Incorrect usage! /ban " and apparently my code is incorrect. Similarly, if the user submits a player that is null, I want a message to be sent that says "Player (player) not found." Whenever I run the command, with or without arguments, it just displays the "usage:" in my plugin.yml.

```
 public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String label, String[] args) {

    if (cmd.getName().equals("ban")) {

        if (args.length == 0) {
            sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.DARK_RED + "Incorrect usage! /ban <player>");
            return false;
        }

    }

    Player player = Bukkit.getPlayer(args[0]);
    if (player == null) {
        sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Player " + player + " not found.");
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved, I had it registered in my main class incorrectly.